# Ajax FAQ loading using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with left nav with several topics in a list and once you click on the links, I would want to load the questions related to those topics on the right side. On page load, I load the top 10 question in the right area but once user click on one of the topic on left, I want top 10 questions disappear and load the new questions with ajax. All those questions have their own pages and I just need to find a good ajax solution to load them. Please suggest a best way to go about this. I would like to acheive this usign jquery

Here is rough example of my code

- Topic 1
- Topic 2
- Topic 3
- Topic 4

This is question 1
This is answer 1 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the pages.

```
$('#topic').load('topics/topic1.html');
```

where `#topic` is the `id` of the container you want to load the answer into.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the entire content at one go into corresponding

```
<div id="ans1"></div>
<div id="ans2"></div>
<div id="ans3"></div>
```

but so only ans1 div on initial load and hide the remaining.

when u click on question2 hyperlink hide ans1 div and show the ans2 div.

Answer (score 0):

repeating your html, and adding a landing spot for the load function:

```
    <ul>
        <li>Topic 1
             <div class="Top10Questions"></div>
        </li>
        <li>Topic 2 <div class="Top10Questions"></div></li>
        <li>Topic 3 <div class="Top10Questions"></div></li>
        <li>Topic 4 <div class="Top10Questions"></div></li>
        </ul>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(
     function(event){
        $("li").click(function(event){
//hide all the questions, you only want to see the topic they clicked on
           $(".Top10Questions").hide();
           $(this).find(".Top10Questions").load("urlToGetAnswer", {json:"of",url:"param",key:"value pairs"}, function(data, text, xhr){
      $(this).show();
    });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @junoonis k, new code hides all the questions except the topic that the user clicked on.  your Url and params will need to supply the html questions content.

Comment: But now the only issue I am having is this: Once the content load in the #content Area, Jquery script doesn't get applied to the new content. For instance in the new content area I have Questions and Answers and Answer div is hidden with jquery and open opens up when you click on the questions div. It works on it's own but when I load this page using ajax within my Content Div, it doesn't apply any JS to it. Any idea why? maybe because I am loading the new ajax Content after the document.ready?

Comment: Thanks Defy, I was able to acheive this by using this tutorial:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/