# Ajax-style FAQ using a CMS?

Tags: ajax, content-management-system, wordpress

We plan to create a FAQ website. It will include two types of content:

1. **Lists** of questions (FAQs), and
2. HTML for each answer.

When user chooses a list and clicks a question, the answer will load in Ajax style.

A very similar approach was described here: [Ajax FAQ loading using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249235/ajax-faq-loading-using-jquery)

But, before we start developing our own CMS, we would like to make sure that no existing solution is directly applicable. So, my question is: are you aware of any existing CMS for creating Ajax-style FAQs?

We are particularly interested in WordPress plugins (one is listed in my own answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I found that are likely to be applicable:

- [WP DS FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ds-faq/): FAQ management tool for WordPress. Replaces specific code on a page with a pre-defined list of questions and answers. Requires WordPress version 2.7 or higher, compatible up to 3.2.1. Last ipdated in August 2011.
- [Core Design FAQ plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/faq/12162) for Joomla. FAQ is created out of a K2 content module. Requires Joomla version 1.7. Last ipdated in August 2011.